# How can i load a package based on the sdk version in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to add the 'camera' package to my application. However, i would like to make my application compatible with as most devices as possible, so i don't want to change the sdk version.

Is it possible to detect the sdk version at runtime and decide to load the camera package only if the device is compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

Use [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) package, that will give you access to more information about both Android and IOS.

[Check the complete example by flutter team's packages](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/device_info/device_info/lib/device_info.dart).

If you want, you can use Platform Channel to build it in your own way.

Comment: While this is very helpful and solves part of the problem, how would I load a new package after detecting the api version?

Comment: The example link is broken